# jQuery toggle cookie not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I am trying to toggle cookie with jquery cookie plugin. This is how my code looks. the toggle works fine and the cookie is set. the cookie is being saved in browser which I can view with chrome developer tools but the toggle state is not being saved.

```
    if(jQuery.cookie('toggledesc') == 1){
            jQuery('.cat_table .hentry').addClass('active_plgn');
            jQuery('.cat_table .hentry .desc_trigger').removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
            jQuery('.desc_inner').css({"display":"block"});

        }

    //when clicked on .expand_desc set cookie/delete cookie
    jQuery( ".expand_desc" ).toggle(function() {
        jQuery('.cat_table .hentry').addClass('active_plgn');
        jQuery('.cat_table .hentry .desc_trigger').addClass("fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o");
        jQuery('.desc_inner').slideDown();
        jQuery.cookie('toggledesc', 1, { expires: 7, path: '/'});
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.cat_table .hentry').removeClass('active_plgn');
        jQuery('.cat_table .hentry .desc_trigger').removeClass("fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o");
        jQuery('.desc_inner').slideUp();
        jQuery.cookie('toggledesc', null);
    });
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the JQuery Cookie readme (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you remove cookies with the following:

```
$.removeCookie('the_cookie');
```

You must use the same path, domain and secure options, so for your code you should do the following:

```
jQuery.removeCookie('toggledesc', { path: '/' });
```

I am unable to test this at the moment but hopefully this fixes your problem.

Comment: That is strange it is not working for you.  I wrote up a jsFiddle for it, and it seems to be working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/LbNU3/  Perhaps you can write up a jsfiddle with more of your code for me to see?

Comment: your example jsfiddle isn't working properly. when I click the "toggle" button nothing happens.